# FireFox print options

Tags: firefox, printing

how i can customise firefox print options with javascript, without display the print dialog.

i found this ff extention ( https://addons.mozilla.org/fr/firefox/addon/8966 ) , but he cant set the page format (A4 or A5)

thanks

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the source code for that extension, it looks like it does support setting `paperHeight` and `paperWidth`, so you could indeed set the page format to A4 or A5.

However, is your goal to control the printer settings for your own personal browser?  Or are you hoping to customize options for your *visitors*?

If your goal is to bypass the print dialog when someone visiting your site tries to print, that's not possible in any major browser.  Browsers leave control over print preferences entirely with the user, and websites cannot change that through JavaScript or any other means.

If you just want a way to control your own personal browser, that extension does look like the right way to go.

Comment: it's not an internet application it's an intranet app, so there is another print solutions for web app ?