# How to hide web url on print for firefox

Tags: javascript, css, firefox

When I print a webpage from Firefox, it automatically adds a header and footer including the website title, URL, date, and page number.

I previously looked at [this question for IE and Opera](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1960939/disabling-browser-print-options-headers-footers-margins-from-page) and [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2192806/can-i-remove-the-url-from-my-print-css-so-the-web-address-doesnt-print), but I need to remove the header/footer specifically in Firefox.

Is it possible to hide the header and footer programmatically using JavaScript or CSS?

Comment: That is browser specific feature which is not handled by JavaScript or CSS

Comment: Is this your own header/footer? - as in part of your website? or is it added by the browser?

Comment: @Xeano i used jquery printelement,while i print/save the document it saves with the current browser url as header,is it possible to remove it?

Comment: Duplicate question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1960939/disabling-browser-print-options-headers-footers-margins-from-page , http://stackoverflow.com/questions/255534/remove-the-default-browser-header-and-footer-when-printing-html , http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2192806/can-i-remove-the-url-from-my-print-css-so-the-web-address-doesnt-print , etc..

Comment: @Noyo i referred it the question illustrates only on ie and opera ,and other two says that theres no way programmatically,so it cant be done in firefox?i m specific about firefox friend

Comment: The answer is the same for Firefox: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1282178/firefox-print-options . There are extensions (e.g. https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/js-print-setup/ ) to remove the header & footer for yourself, but you can't ensure that the extension is installed for all the visitors to the site. If you have a "print" link to generate a PDF of the site, as referred to in other answers, that could be a workaround.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7704916/firefox-printing-options-within-a-webpage/7704941#7704941

Comment: http://www.mintprintables.com/print-tips/header-footer-windows/

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7704916/firefox-printing-options-within-a-webpage/7704941

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you are using firefox do the following :

Go to the 'File' --> 'Page Setup' item on the menu, and then select the 'Margins & Header/Footer' tab in the dialog.

[image]

you should be able to change the drop-downs to set the Title or URL to –blank– instead, which will prevent them from printing. Note that you could also use this to put the page numbers at the top instead of the bottom if you prefer that.
This was the normal approach to print without headers/url in general

Comment: nice idea but i cant say to every end user to do this configuration :(

Comment: This answer no longer works in Firefox 29; the Page Setup menu no longer contains the "Margins & Header/Footer" tab.